# Why is browserify pulling in a lib 2 times? - Browserify

Tags: browserify

I have an `Angular` app where I use `browserify` to manage my dependencies.  I am also using `momentjs` to do all my time manipulation.  I have several modules that I am using `browserify` to build, but it is pulling in `momentjs` more than once, even when I use the `external` command.  Here is my code.  First I have a base module that has all of my shared libs:

```
require('angular');
require('angular-route');
require('moment');
```

Here is the code I use to `browserify` in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
browserify().require('./js/donor/donor-libs.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('donor-libs.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

This builds out fine and has the libs that I would expect including `momentjs`.

Now I go to build a module that is dependent on this module.  `momentjs` is used in this module.  Here is the code that I use to build the module:

```
    browserify().require('./js/donor/history-module.js')
        .external('./js/donor/donor-libs.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(filename))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

Now when I look in my `build` directory, I have `momentjs` in both the `donor-libs.js` and my `history-module.js`.  Why doesn't it recognize that I have already required in `momentjs` in my `donor-libs.js`?  What do I need to do to only require in 3rd party libs one time?  What don't I understand about the `external` command?

Answer (score 0):

The reason libs are being pulled in multiple times is that the `external` command is being used improperly.  `external` is expecting a path or an array of paths that will `external`ized.  `external` will not look through a `js` file and find the `require`d files and then not pull them in other modules.  The code should of looked something like this

```
.external('angular', 'angular-route', 'moment')
```

or the path to the `require`d lib.  This would of externalized these files and fixed the problem of a lib being pulled in multiple times.